# Method does not get run

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nslog

I am trying to run a non-void function returning an NSArray, but when I run it, there's not even a log line:

```
- (NSArray *) arrayFunction
{
    return myList;
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
- (void) myMainFunction
{
    [self arrayFunction];
}
```

I also tried with NSLog and a void function instead of NSArray, but that won't show up either.

It is a NSView class.

Thanks for you help!

**EDIT: ** Full Code:
Implementation file:

```
#import "LogNavigator.h"

@implementation LogNavigator

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
    }

    [self myMainFunction];
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
}

- (NSArray *) arrayFunction
{
    // # Get the list of .txt files, this part works correctly as expected in CodeRunner
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"];

    NSArray *directoryList = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:nil]
                          pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"txt", nil]];
return directoryList;
}

- (void) myMainFunction
{
    [self arrayFunction];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you show the full code. In the code you have posted in the question nothing will actually happen when the code runs. Have you tried adding a breakpoint to check that the function call (in myMainFunction) is actually being called?

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply @Fogmeister i just used the breakpoints, non of the functions are being called it seems.

Comment: Why are you calling a method from a function? Why not just call the method directly?

Comment: How are you initialising this NSView class. Can you show us that code?

Comment: Where is this `NSLog` you are talking about? And where do you call `myMainFunction` please share all relevant code.

Comment: Abizern sure I tried as written in the question with non-void function and NSLog, that won't work either. @Suhas I will edit my answer to show the full code.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith is the `myMainFunction` function being called? i.e. put a line `NSLog(@"Here!");` just before the line `[self arrayFunction];`. Also, try to show the full code flow. At the moment these are just two functions. There is no flow to it. Where does it start?

Comment: No where in your code do you ever call `myMainFunction` or `arrayFunction` You never call `doItNow2` ever so `doItNow` will never get called. What do you expect to happen if you don't call it? It's not magic.

Comment: Where are you calling `doItNow2`?

Comment: @Popeye swap `arrayFunction` with `doItNow`, and `doItNow2` with `myMainFunction` I only used the simpler example for ease of understanding. I corrected the tiny spelling confusion.

Comment: Yeah I know that I was making a point you need to up date your question. It's not up to us to update it. We where told `myMainFunction` and `arrayFunction` as the names not `doItNow` and `doItNow2`.

Comment: Thanks @Popeye I corrected the tiny spelling confusion.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith btw, these aren't function calls , they are __method__ calls. And in the code you've posted I can't see any calls to `myMainFunction` so how are you expecting the code to be run?

Comment: @JeremiahSmith ever way where do you call `myMainFunction`? It is never called in your code so will never run `arrayFunction`.

Comment: @Abizern corrected the question title, Popeye, I tried before running it by calling the method inside `- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
`, it didn't work, that's why omitted that falsely, corrected it just now.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith and where/how do you call `initWithFrame:`?

Comment: Call this function  [self myMainFunction]; inside drawRect method and check??

Comment: @JeremiahSmith: Why don't you just set a breakpoint in `initWithFrame:` (or add an NSLog) to see if that method is called? - *My guess:* The view is loaded from a nib or storyboard, and `initWithCoder:` is called instead of `initWithFrame:`

Comment: Thanks @Martin R it does not work there either and Hussain Shabbir it doesn't work there either. Also this might help: I basically created an application with nib file and added a class of nsview to it and wrote these code lines in it.

Comment: I think Martin has the correct answer.  When they say classes have one designated initialiser, the omit to tell you about `initWithCoder` which is called when an object is us archived, which is what is happening when you load objects from a nib.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith: Is your custom view loaded at all? - And you did not tell us if `initWithFrame` or `initWithCoder` is actually called.

Comment: `initWithFrame` is does not seem to work as expected, setting a breakpoint there reveals no activity.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith: Is your NSView subclass *used at all* ?? Is there any view in your nib or storyboard which has the "Custom class" set to LogNavigator?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin R I think that is the error we are getting closer, all I wanted to do is work with the existing application nib file, but there was only the AppDelegate class available. From what I have learned one has to create NSView class for it, and I tried with NSObject class as well, which didn't work. Somehow I have to associate that class to the nib file. I assume that could be done in interface builder by associating that class in some way...

Comment: @Martin R I tried with AppDelegate this time, although I shouldn't, but the result is weird, it displays the checking log function, and calls all functions, but the text files on the desktop are not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this custom `NSView` is created using Interface Builder then you should override `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self myMainFunction];
}
```

Note, however, that you are ignoring the return from `arrayFunction`, so it's feasible the compiler might omit the call entirely during an optmimized release build if it can determine no side effects of the call.

**EDIT**: Note that you need to set the `NSView`-derived class within the **view** of the window within `MainMenu.xib`, using IB, in order for this method to be triggered when the view is loaded.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith And you are loading the view via a nib?

Comment: No, but I should as Martin R pointed out earlier. But am not sure how I would do that, all I want is write a class to my standard XCode pre-set nib file.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith The "normal" way of doing this (the way I certainly prefer) is to create a separate NIB file for the view and use an `NSViewController` to load and manage the NIB.  This process is well documented by Apple.

Comment: I don't want to create a new view, all I really want is to have a class around the pre-set nib file from XCode.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith So this is the default "Single View" (might be called something different) Xcode project with a `MainMenu.xib` file included?  In that case, setting the class of the view within the window (from within IB) should trigger the `awakeFromNib` method I mention in my answer.

Comment: thanks. Yes it is that case, I tried associating the window to that class, with `awakeFromNib`, but no avail, breakpoint also revealed no activity.

Comment: You set the association in interface builder.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith No, it needs to be the **view** within the window, not the window. The custom view must be derived from `NSView`.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe now it calls all the functions checking the NSLog checking and breakpoints, but the `arrayFunction` returns nothing, however when running the code in CodeRunner, it still works and returns the NSArray...

Comment: @JeremiahSmith OK, I believe your question has been answered.  If you want further assistance WRT the array return then please start a new SO question.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, could you please amend your answer with your pre-last comment? I will accept it then.

Comment: @trojanfoe I still have a little problem here, now I can't connect the elements of interface builder with the header file, and if I use a pre-written IBOutlet, it shows red warning symbols next to Key Path of both controller and model object. How could I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: @JeremiahSmith You should start a new SO question.

Answer (score 0):

When objects are loaded from a nib (or a Storyboard) The normal initialiser is not called, instead `initWithCoder` is called.

When setting up objects from a nib, you should override `initWithCoder` and put your initialiser code in there instead.

If you need to access or set up other objects in the nib as part of initialisation, then `awakeFromNib` is a better method to override, because it is called after all the other nib objects have been loaded.

**edit**

When you added the view object to the nib, did you specify it's class as `LogNavigator`? This is something that people frequently forget to do.

Comment: All I wanted to do was write a class to the XCode pre-set nib file..., there was none pre-delivered by XCode for this application.

Comment: If your project didn't come with a nib file, you need to tell Xcode what the initial nib or storyboard to load is.  If you're on Xcode 5 the is done in the main project page.

Comment: Thanks @Abizern sorry it came with nib file, but not with associated class, that's the problem.